# Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints

CREATE TABLE BuyInsurance(
ID  INT primary key IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
Cus_ID   AS   ('CUS' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (5), ID), (5))) PERSISTED,
us_Name      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Cus_ADD       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Cus_phone     BIGINT       NULL,
Pol_Num       AS           ('POL' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (5), ID), (5))) PERSISTED,
Pol_Date      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Pol_Duration  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Veh_Num       BIGINT       NULL,
Veh_Name     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Veh_Model     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Veh_Version   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Veh_Rate     BIGINT       NULL,
Veh_Warranty  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Veh_BodyNum   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Veh_EngineNum VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Cus_Add_Prove VARCHAR (50) NULL,

);

CREATE TABLE Vehicle_Information (
Vehicle_ID            INT PRIMARY KEY         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
Vehicle_Name          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Vechicle_Owner_Name   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Vehicle_Model         VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Vehicle_Version      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Vehicle_Rate          BIGINT       NULL,
Vehicle_Body_Number   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Vehicle_Engine_Number VARCHAR (50) NULL,
Vehicle_Number        BIGINT       NULL,

);

create table BillingInformation (
ID  int PRIMARY key identity (1,1),
Cus_ID int foreign key references BuyInsurance (ID),
Pol_Num  varchar foreign key references BuyInsurance (ID),
Cus_phone bigint foreign key references BuyInsurance (ID),
BillN0 bigint ,
Vehicle_Name varchar foreign key references Vehicle_Information (Vehicle_ID),
Vehicle_Model varchar foreign key references Vehicle_Information (Vehicle_ID),
Vehicle_Rate varchar foreign key references Vehicle_Information (Vehicle_ID),
Vehicle_Engine_Number varchar foreign key references Vehicle_Information (Vehicle_ID),
Vehicle_Body_Number varchar foreign key references Vehicle_Information (Vehicle_ID),
Date date,
Amount bigint
);SELECT * FROM BillingInformation

[image: Error I'm getting]

Comment: The error message is 100% clear, so what is your question?

Comment: In the error: `is not the same data type` IS _the clue_. One side of the FK is an `int` the other side is a `varchar` which won't work.